# Is an argument of zero a good option to allow user to say they want all results?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a function that will allow user to return a set of results. For the purpose of this discussion, assume it is returning a sequence of objects. I want to provide a facility for the caller to limit the number of objects returned.

In python:

```
def get_records(max=0):
    # snipped ..
```

The `max` parameter will limit the number of records returned. If it is zero, I will return all. Is this good API design ?

Comment: I prefer -1 to 0.  It has an added benefit in that if you interpret it as an unsigned integer you will get the largest possible integer value.

Comment: @aroth, that's assuming the language being used is using two's complement under the covers. Just raising the point since the question is tagged language-agnostic (even C doesn't _guarantee_ this since the sign/magnitude encoding scheme would turn -1 into 1, though, admittedly, I can't say I've ever seen such a beast in the wild recently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as behaviour is documented, you can use any value you want, provided it's outside the scope of what people would consider a "normal" parameter. By that I mean you would not use `2` as the special value if clients of your code would ever want two things returned.

So, provided there's not a valid use case for returning zero things <sup>(a)</sup>, then zero is as good a value as any to indicate "all items".

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You *may* have a valid use case where there are side-effects in calling the function. An example is an arbitrary list where you call `getFirst(n)` on it and that first sorts the list then returns the first `n` items.

Clients may wish to call your code with `getFirst(0)` to just sort the list without getting any values.

Of course, I'd implement a totally *separate* function for that myself so this is a slightly contrived example but it hopefully illustrates the point I'm trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

If the language supports overloading, then I would use an overload without the `max` parameter to indicate that all rows were requested. Alternatively, given nullable values and default values, I might use a single method with a nullable integer parameter with a default value of null.

In C#:

```
public IEnumerable<Record> GetRecords(int? maximumRecords = null);
```